# How to find the coordinates of a particular text in pdf?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried in python using fitz, but its simply highlighting the text in PDF. I am not getting how to extract X and Y coordinates of that particular PDF files.

This is my code, can anyone help me in this

```
import fitz

### READ IN PDF
doc = fitz.open("C:\\Users\\vinit\\Desktop\\Input\\InputPDF.pdf")

for page in doc:
    ### SEARCH
    text = "Authorised Signature"
    text_instances = page.search_for(text)

    ### HIGHLIGHT
    for inst in text_instances:
        highlight = page.add_highlight_annot(inst)
        highlight.update()

### OUTPUT
doc.save("output.pdf", garbage=4, deflate=True, clean=True)
```

or is there any another method in python to get the coordinates of a particular text from PDF?

Comment: what will you do with the coordinates?

Comment: @LeiYang want to integrate with another tool..... But i am not getting how to extract coordinates for particular text in PDF

Comment: i think you can try some other tools such as pikepdf, and opencv.

Comment: @LeiYang is there any link which can i use it as for reference.. i am new to python

Comment: and i doubt pdf has concept of absolute coordinates? my idea is convert pdf to image (https://pypi.org/project/pdf2image/) then use ocr(opencv) to recognize the text and its coordinates.

Comment: can you give me code for this?

Comment: 'want to integrate with another tool' --- not a strong reason for me, sorry.

Comment: Actually i want to find text coordinates in python and want to use those coordinates in uipath... But there are some activities in uipath which can give me coordinates of element but its not giving correct coordinates that's why i am using python for this